# Undefined offset: 0 error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having this error on my code

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\rekmovie\paginator.php on line 29

here is the full code

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$conn=mysql_select_db('rektechnologies'); 
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } // include your code to connect to DB.
if (!empty($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sql = "select * from videos order by id desc LIMIT $start_from, 10";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$con); 
?> 
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?> 
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $row["path"]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
}; 
?>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$con); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10);
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<a href='paginator.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
</table>
```

can anyone help me with the error

Comment: $total_records = $row[0];

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result);
```

to:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, but you're trying to access `$row[0]`, which expects an indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysql_fetch_assoc, but then trying to access the column name by integer

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
```

use either

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result);
$total_records = $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
```

Comment: the error is gone but i am trying to display 2 rows from the database but nothing is shown <?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result)) { 
?> 
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $row["path"]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
}; 
?>

Answer (score 0):

change the query to `SELECT COUNT(*) as some_alias FROM videos`

and then use `$total_records = $row['some_alias'];`